# C# application installed on a virtual machine and pointed to a sql 2008 R2 database doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, virtual-machine

I have a c# application installed on Virtual machine and the application works fine when I point it to a sql 2005 or 2012 database but it gives the following error when I point it to sql 2008 R2 database:

> "Error starting application: System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object."

I don't have this error using sql 2005 or 2012.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code? Otherwise you should probably ask this at the developers website/forum.

Comment: Are there any other changes in the connection strings but the server names? Can you post the connection strings?

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't have access to the source code. its a windows application.

Comment: Connection String: <connectionString name="Sql Connection String">
          <parameters>
            <parameter name="Server" value="(local)" isSensitive="false" />
            <parameter name="Database" value="Compliance 7 March 2013" isSensitive="false" />
            <parameter name="Integrated Security" value="True" isSensitive="false" />
            <parameter name="User ID" value="sa" isSensitive="false" />
            <parameter name="Password" value="Password$$"  isSensitive="false" />
          </parameters>
        </connectionString>

Comment: I actually installed and uninstalled sql 2012 and then installed sql 2008 R2, the application is working now. I still don't know what is the problem because I can't tell the client to do that and is waiting for the solution which I don't know

Comment: Version 1 - It seemed that your SQL Server 2008 R2 installation was named instanse but not default. In such case you can't access it as `(local)`. Now you installed it as default instanse and you connection string became operational. Version 2 - You didn't run deployment script for your application and database was not creating. Version 3 - You didn't specify SQL Server security during your 2008R2 installation or specified wrong password for user `sa`. Unfortunately only Sherlock Holmes can help with such wide installation issues.